# in a struct, scanf returns var address not value

Tags: c, struct, scanf

I tried to print the value of an int variable of a struct but it prints out the address instead. I don't know why, here is the code:

```
struct data{
    char name[20];
    int age[100];
};

typedef struct data dataobj;

int main() {
    dataobj element;
    printf("enter a name:\n");
    gets(element.name);
    printf("name is: %s\n",element.name);
    printf("enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%d",&element.age);
    printf("number is: %d",element.age);
    return 0;
}
```

output here:

```
enter a name:
John
name is: John
enter a number:
30
number is: 6356352
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 7.278 s
Press any key to continue.
```

You can see it doesn't print 30 as I wanted to, instead it prints 6356352 (which should be the address of element.age var)

Comment: One name of 20 characters with 100 ages?

Comment: yeah it was a test, forgot to change the size

Comment: Into which of the array's elements do you want to read the value?

Comment: You probably want to change age in the struct to just `int age`, why have it as an array?

Comment: `int age[100]` is an *array* of 100 `int`s! Into which one do you want to read into the 0th, the 1st, the 2nd, the 99th?

Comment: Solved, thanks guys I don't know why CodeBlocks crashed when I used one variable instead of the array, now its working

Comment: Note: **Never ever** use `gets`! It has been removed from the standard for security reasons. A standard compliant implementation should warn for missing prototype. Use `fgets` on `stdin` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `gets`, is deprecated in C99 and removed from C11

Instead, use `fgets`:

```
char *ptr;

fgets(element.name, sizeof element.name, stdin);
/* Remove the trailing newline */
ptr = strchr(element.name, '\n');
if (ptr != NULL) {
    *ptr = '\0';
}
```

And `age` is not an `int` but an array of `int`s:

```
struct data{
    char name[20];
    int age[100];
};
```

change

```
scanf("%d",&element.age);
printf("number is: %d",element.age);
```

to

```
scanf("%d",&(element.age[0]));
printf("number is: %d",element.age[0]);
```

in order to read into the age's 1st element (sitting at index 0), or simply use a plain `int` instead of an array

Comment: Alright thanks! actually I messed it up, didn't mean to create an array but if I just do: int ages; the programs crashes.

Comment: And how can I replace gets? scanf doesn't take the whole string if there are spaces in it

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you mean to have the `age` property as an array of 100 `int`s; in the case that you don't, if you change your `struct` definition to only have a single `int`:

```
struct data{
    char name[20];
    int age;
};
```

the code you provided works just fine. If you're looking to bound the value of age, you wouldn't want to do so using an array. Using an array like that implies each `dataobj` is described by a name and 100 ages. Instead, consider adding a run-time check such as:

```
if (element.age < 0 || element.age > 99) {
    printf("Bad age value\n");
}
```

Comment: Yeah, now it is working, I don't know why CodeBlocks kept crushing when I used a single var, I tried with an array and it worked but forgot to change the code.. now its not crashing anymore. cheers

Answer (score 0):

in your code consider this statement.

```
scanf("%d",&element.age);
```

Here, age is of type array size 100 integer elements. So inside your memory a series of 100 integers was created and the address of starting element is stored in other pointer variable(int your case age). So, when you are scanning value, you are trying to manipulate the base address of your array which is not possible. This comes  under logical error which can be traced only by understanding. So, just remember one thing.

```
int age[100]
```

this is a declaration in which compiler creates a pointer and 100  integer variables(contiguous). And the address of first variable is stored in pointer which takes name given to array.

So, when you are trying to print it it is printing the base address array age[100].

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking to do is store away the age into the first element of your age array:

```
scanf("%d", element.age);
printf("Age is %d\n", element.age[0]);
```

Basically, 99 elements will go unused. Another approach would be to increment the value in the age array that contains the age. In other words, if the user enters age 30 then you would basically do an element.age[29]++;

In this way you would keep all 100 values at zero, except for the age that you want to boost up (the age the user entered)

Another thing that may be good practice is to use a separate variable when working with scanf. For example, this code fragment:

```
int incoming_age;
scanf("%d", &incoming_age);
element.age[0] = incoming_age;
```

Once you have the input scanned into the incoming_age variable, you can do a variety of things with it. It can make the code a little more readable.